# JMenuItems don't show in JDialog

Tags: swing, jdialog, jmenuitem

This is probably a dumb question, but I just can't see it!  I have Swing app that uses a popup menu.  It works fine, but I want to make the menu persistent (i.e. until I close it).  I have basically changed the JPopupMenu to  JDialog, and I am getting the JDialog panel, but the menu items are invisible!  It's probably something very obvious, so I'll probably be embarrassed!   Here is part of the code:

```
  JDialog buildNewItemMenu(DrawFBP base) {
    JDialog jd = new JDialog();
    jd.setSize(200, 300);
    JMenuItem menuItem = null;
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    label2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    JMenu menu = new JMenu();       
    jd.add(menu);       
    jd.setVisible(true);
    menu.setVisible(true);
    menu.add(label2);
    menu.addSeparator();
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Component");
    menuItem.addActionListener(base);
    menu.add(menuItem);
    ....
    menu.addSeparator();
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Enclosure");
    menuItem.addActionListener(base);
    menu.add(menuItem);     
    return jd;
```

Comment: For better help sooner, port an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Have you tried directly adding the JMenuItem to JDialog instead of JMenu? Besides, the line `menu.add(label2);` sounds weird, why would you add a `JLabel` to a menu?

Comment: Thanks @jfpoilpret, tried that.  I did finally get it working - by changing the JMenu to a JPanel, and adding this statement:    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: hmm .. something like a detached JToolBar?

Comment: Hi @kleopatra - almost exactly that: a box along the bottom of the screen with radio buttons - looks pretty good, if I do say so myself!

Comment: then ... why don't you use a JToolBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will close this - as I said in the comment, changing the JMenu to a JPanel and adding

```
  panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

fixed the problem, but I plan to tackle the problem a different way.  Thanks anyway!